# Wait for async.each to finish via await before proceeding

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to wait for async.eachLimit to complete before proceeding.

My code:

```
await async.eachLimit(myList, async (item)=>{
  await processItem(item)
})

console.log("all done");
```

but I always get the "all done" before everything is processed. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Could you show us what `processItem` does please?

Comment: const testFunc =  async (item) => {
  const rand = Math.random() * 10 * 1000
  setTimeout( ()=>{
    console.log(item);
    return true;
  }, rand)
}

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it like this:

```
await new Promise( (resolve, reject)=>{
  async.eachLimit(myList, async (item)=>{
    await processItem(item)
  }, (err)=> {
  if(err) reject(err)
  else resolve()
})
```

The problem was that for some reason, async.eachLimit wasn't returning an awaitable promise.

Comment: Don’t you pass anything to resolve?

Answer (score -1):

You can try `Promise.all()`, which returns a promise that only resolves when all the promises in a list are resolved.

```
await Promise.all(myList);
console.log("done");
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can adapt this to your needs ( used 1000 instead of your Math.random.. to run the example faster ).

```js
const test = async () => {

  const list = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

  const testFunc = async (item) => {
    return new Promise( ( res, rej ) => {
      setTimeout( () => {
        console.log(item)
        res( true )
      }, 1000)
    } )
  }

  await Promise.all( list.map( async ( item ) => {
    await testFunc( item )
  } ) )

  console.log("all done")
}

test()
```

Comment: Problem is I need to limit how many parallel jobs are running.